# Checking if a file exists in the same directory with dynamic name based on string within text file?

Tags: file, perl, find

I have to open many text files in multiple directories and replace some strings. So far so good. What I struggle with is, that I have to "extract" a file name from this text file (in my case it's an image name) and check if this file exists within the same directory as the text file.

**Example**:

I have to search for "wordattachment28gf823a0.png" within the text file "How to eat a sandwich.txt" within the folder "How to eat food" and check if "wordattachment28gf823a0.png" exists in the folder "How to eat food".

What I know is basically only the string format is always starting with "wordattachment" and ending with ".png".

My goal is to get a list of missing images like so:

"wordattachment26783dga3.png is missing in folder "How to eat a watermelon""

"wordattachmentjk3381rsa.png is missing in folder "How to eat a carrot""

and so on...

What I have right now is the following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;


my $location=".";

sub find_txt {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;

    if ($F =~ /txt$/ ) {
        #Reading the file
        open (FILEHANDLE,"<$F");
        my $string = do { local $/; <FILEHANDLE> };
        my $imageStr = do { local $/; <FILEHANDLE> };
        print "\nReading file $F ";
    close (FILEHANDLE);

    #replacement actions
    $string =~ s/<a href="http(.*?)\+"/<a href="http$1"/gs; #searching and replacing links with pluses on the end

    $imageStr =~ /wordattachment(.*?).png/;

    if (-e $imageStr) {

    }
    else {
    print FILEHANDLE "$imageStr is missing in $location";
    }

    # Writing the changed file
    open (FILEHANDLE,">$F");
        print FILEHANDLE $string ;
        print FILEHANDLE $imageStr;
    close (FILEHANDLE);
    }
}


find({ wanted => \&find_txt, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
```

What I tried is searching the images and storing them as $imageStr and then checking with the "if (-e $imageStr)" if the corresponding file exists. What I get when running the perl script is the following:

```
Reading file ./How to eat fruit/How to eat a watermelon/README.txt
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at D:\How tos\TEST.pl line 24.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at D:\How tos\TEST.pl line 26.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at D:\How tos\TEST.pl line 30.
print() on closed filehandle FILEHANDLE at D:\How tos\TEST.pl line 30.
Use of uninitialized value in print at D:\How tos\TEST.pl line 36.
```

I obviously done something wrong and I'm not a perl expert as you can see, so help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is first some working code to do what's asked

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find;

my $dir = shift // '.';  #/

find( sub {
    return if not /\.txt$/ or not -f;  # Only .txt plain files

    my $content =  do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $_; <> };

    my ($img_name) = $content =~ /(wordattachment.*?\.png)/;

    if ($img_name and not -e $img_name) { 
        say "Found name \"$img_name\" in a file \"$File::Find::name\" ",
            "but no such file in directory \"$File::Find::dir\"";
    }

    # Make your replacements and rewrite the file
    #$content =~ s/...
    #open my $fh, '>', $_ or die "Can't open $_ for writing: $!";
    #print $fh $content;

}, $dir);
```

I've taken most details from the question.  I did add `.` to make the `.txt` a *file extension*.

Some notes on the code above and on the code in the question

- That regex matches only the first such pattern found and then stops the search
- The code makes liberal use of the fact that the routine `chdir`s into directories, what is very convenient at a number of places.  I don't see a reason to turn that off as in OP
- The code returns if a file isn't a *plain file*, under [-f filetest](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) (or if it doesn't end in `.txt`).  Adjust if that is too restrictive, but note that in the OP only the opening of a file is conditioned on `txt` -- the rest of code runs for all entries! That's what brings most (all?) of those warnings
- There is no reason for two copies of the file contents, since one operation only searches
- There are *far* better ways -- libraries -- to process HTML than with regex

---

It turns out that multiple matches (filenames of images) may indeed be of interest. Then

```
my @img_names = $content =~ /(wordattachment.*?\.png)/g;

foreach my $img_name (@img_names) {
    if (not -e $img_name) { 
        say "Found name \"$img_name\" in a file \"$File::Find::name\" ",
            "but no such file in directory \"$File::Find::dir\"";
    }
}
```

With the modifier `/g` the search continues through the whole string. Then the matches are returned since the match operator is in [list context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) (now because it's assigned to an array so we don't need the parens, which we did need with a single match assigned to scalar in order to provide the list context).  See tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: @schokogabel332  It's a little hard for me to decide what to comment on, please let me know

Comment: One last question: It only matches the first ".png" within a text file. What should I modify to check for multiple occasions where ".png" is found within a text file?

Comment: @schokogabel332 Yeah, that's why I commented -- match with `/g` (globally, what makes it keep going and looking for matches through the whole string) and assign to an array, so `@img_names = .... //g;`.  Then go through image names to check for all.  Will add to the answer in a little while

Comment: @schokogabel332 Added to the answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you soooo soo much :) you made my day

Comment: hey thank you for saying that :))   let me know if more comes up :)

Answer (score -1):

OP's question is poorly articulated in desired result.

Following demo piece of code is accepting one parameter, directory name, on command line. If directory name is not specified then assumed current directory.

The script is taking directory **items** checks if **item** is the directory then *dives into directory* otherwise checks **item** for extension match, processes the **item** on match for defined **regex**.

Processing reads matching file into variable and extracts *matching filenames* into array.

Then loops through obtained result above and checks if file with such name exists, plain file and is readable.

If the check is not satisfied above requirements then a message is printed in console window.

NOTE: the script was not tested on real data due absence of such

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = shift || '.';
my $regex = qr/(wordattachment.*?\.png)/;

check_files($dir,'txt',$regex);

sub check_files {
    my $dir   = shift;
    my $ext   = shift;
    my $regex = shift;

    for (glob("$dir/*") {
        check_files($_, $ext, $regex) if -d $_;
        next unless /\.$ext$/;
        report_missing($_, $regex);
    }
}

sub report_missing {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $regex = shift;

    my $data = read_file($fname);
    my @expected_files = $data =~ /$regex/gs;

    for my $file (@expected_files ) {
        say "File $file fails check" unless -e -f -r $file;
    }
}

sub read_file {
    my $fname = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't to read $fname";

    my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };

    close $fh;

    return $data;
}
```